# Where are questions about the HTTP specification on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Where would questions about details regarding the HTTP specification be on-topic?

I have found two questions so far that fit the bill (the first one being mine, and the reason I started this Meta thread):

- [Super User: *What if the form-data boundary is contained in the attached file?*](https://superuser.com/q/897897/114760)
- [Stack Overflow: *Http Header - Cache-Control: max-age behaviour?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14092313/617937)

A moderator recommended moving my question to Stack Overflow, and the second question is already there, but I'm hesitant. I feel a question is only relevant on Stack Overflow if you have an actual piece of code written and have questions on how to "fix" a specific problem. Not about the nuances of W3C specifications.

Comment: If someone answers and they get shed loads of upvotes it magically becomes on topic in their eyes. So usually where it gets the most squatters' rights.

Comment: No moderator suggested moving the question

Comment: @random Ah, my mistake, I must have seen the high rep and mentally classified him as a moderator, but I see now [DavidPostill](http://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) is just a regular very qualified user.

Comment: This is probably the best place: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg